# Tex4ht on document: error "\leftmargin doesn't match its definition" when  \small is used in acronym name

Tags: errors, tex4ht

Is it possible to change the settings of dvi compilation in tex4ht? I ask, because I get a strange errors, when trying to generate html for my latex file:

```
! Use of \leftmargin doesn't match its definition.
     [exec] \@listi ...argin \leftmargini \parsep 4\p@ \@plus 
     [exec]                                                   2\p@ \@minus \p@ \topsep 8...
     [exec] l.18 \begin{itemize}
     [exec]                     
     [exec] ? 
     [exec] ! Emergency stop.
     [exec] \@listi ...argin \leftmargini \parsep 4\p@ \@plus 
     [exec]                                                   2\p@ \@minus \p@ \topsep 8...
     [exec] l.18 \begin{itemize}
```

I do not have any errors like that, when generating pdf or dvi (using texify.exe)

UPDATE. I have created a sample tex that produces the error:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}    
\usepackage[style=altlist,          %Verwendung eines Glossars
                        nonumberlist,
                        numberedsection,
                        acronym,
                        toc]{glossaries}    
\newacronym{ie}{{\small IE}}{}
\newacronym{ml}{{\small ML}}{}    
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}    
\chapter{Example}
\glsresetall
\subsection{Fundamentals} 
\gls{ie}


\begin{table}[tpb]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|l|X|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Doc No} & \textbf{Text} \\ \hline
                         5641 &   Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium    \\ \hline
             9382 &   Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium  \\ \hline 
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
    \caption{AAA \label{tbl:unstr_example}}
\end{table}


 \gls{ie}

\appendix


\printglossary[toctitle=Acronyms,type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary[toctitle=Glossary, type=main]

\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\bibliography{}
\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}    
\end{document}
```

The error message for the sample doc is (run: htlatex test_doc.tex):

```
! Use of \leftmargin doesn't match its definition.
\@listi ...argin \leftmargini \parsep 4\p@ \@plus 
                                                   2\p@ \@minus \p@ \topsep 8...
l.2 \begin{theglossary}
                       \glossaryheader
 ? 
! Emergency stop.
\@listi ...argin \leftmargini \parsep 4\p@ \@plus 
                                                   2\p@ \@minus \p@ \topsep 8...
 l.2 \begin{theglossary}
                         \glossaryheader
```

The error does not appear if I remove `\small` from acronym definition: `\newacronym{ie}{{\small IE}}{information extraction}`

Comment: tex4ht loads and manipulates tons of definitions. Without a small, complete example that demonstrates the error and informations about how exactly you are using tex4ht *nobody* will be able to help you.

Comment: I will provide an example as soon as I manage to create a small document, which triggers the same error. I get this error trying to create html from my whole thesis (using ETHthesis) and I have difficulties to capture the exact fragment, which causes this error.

Comment: Well the error message concerns itemize. So start with a document containing only an itemize environment and your complete preamble. If it triggers the same error start to remove  packages from the preamble.

Comment: Make your example smaller. I'm quite certain that 90% of your example is not relevant. Also replace it possible your class with a standard one.

Comment: Right, I have reduced the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a tex4ht problem. This stripped down example already breaks with pdflatex + makeglossaries:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[style=altlist,          %Verwendung eines Glossars
                        nonumberlist,
                        numberedsection,
                        acronym,
                        toc]{glossaries}
\newacronym{ie}{{\small IE}}{}
%\newacronym{ie}{{\protect\small IE}}{}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\gls{ie}
\gls{ie}
\printglossary[toctitle=Acronyms,type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

The solution is to protect the command `\small`.